# Index and Iterate over CollectionType in swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have code which is basically like this:

```
func arrayHalvesEqual(data:[UInt8]) -> Bool {
    let midPoint = data.count / 2
    for i in 0..<midPoint {
        let b = data[i]
        let b2 = data[i + midPoint]
        if b != b2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This works fine, but sometimes I want to pass in Arrays, and other times ArraySlice. I thought I'd change it to use generics and the `CollectionType` protocol, which converts as follows:

```
func arrayHalvesEqual<ByteArray : CollectionType where ByteArray.Generator.Element == UInt8>(data:ByteArray) -> Bool {
    let midPoint = data.count / 2
    for i in 0..<midPoint {
        let b = data[i]
        let b2 = data[i + midPoint]
        if b != b2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

```
error: binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'ByteArray.Index.Distance'
    for i in 0..<midPoint {
```

I can switch the for loop to `for i in data.indices` which makes that compile, but then I can no longer divide it by 2 to get the midPoint, as data.indices returns the abstract `CollectionType.Index` whereas / 2 is an Int.

Is it possible to do something like this in Swift? Can I bridge between an abstract protocol Index type and some real type I can do maths on?

P.S: I've seen and found other examples for iterating over the whole collection by using `indices` and `enumerate`, but I explicitly only want to iterate over half the collection which requires some sort of division by 2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the method to collections which are indexed
by `Int`:

```
func arrayHalvesEqual<ByteArray : CollectionType where ByteArray.Index == Int, ByteArray.Generator.Element == UInt8>
    (data:ByteArray) -> Bool { ... }
```

This covers both `Array` and `ArraySlice`.

And if you use `indices.startIndex` instead of `0` as initial index
then it suffices to restrict the index type to `IntegerType`.
Also the data type `UInt8` can be replaced by a generic `Equatable`,
and the entire method shortened to

```
func arrayHalvesEqual<ByteArray : CollectionType where ByteArray.Index : IntegerType, ByteArray.SubSequence.Generator.Element : Equatable>
    (data:ByteArray) -> Bool {

        let midPoint = (data.indices.endIndex - data.indices.startIndex)/2
        let firstHalf = data[data.indices.startIndex ..< midPoint]
        let secondHalf = data[midPoint ..< data.indices.endIndex]
        return !zip(firstHalf, secondHalf).contains { $0 != $1 }
}
```